# How to assign a value to a class instance variable?

Tags: python, class

I am building a programming language and I need help
I have the first code snippet on varObject.py and the second on lexer.py:

**varObject.py**

```
class VariableObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        type(self).variables = {}

    def set_variable(self, name, value):
        self.variables[name] = value
```

**lexer.py**

```
from varObject import VariableObject

class Lexer(object):

    def __init__(self, source_code):
        self.source_code = source_code

    def tokenize(self):
        varsdb = VariableObject()
        varsdb.set_variable("x", 5)
        print(varsdb.variables)
```

The expected output is `{"x": 5}`, but the actual output is `{}`.

Comment: there is nowhere in code above setting value `5` on `x` key in self.variables dictionary. You probably didn't paste some code.

Comment: I fixed this and now you can actually understand. Thanks for reporting

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

I feel like you are missing some key parts of code here but you just have to declare a variable in the scope of the class. Look at the example on the link. Hopefully this helps